# Are saturation temperature and boiling point same thing?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, phase-diagram

In my view they both are same thing.
**Boiling point** is the temp at which vapor pressure of water becomes greater than pressure outside vessel. Liquid water change it's phase during this. And.
At a given pressure the temperature at which a pure substance change it's phase is **saturation temperature**.
At 101.325 kPa water boils at 100°C. So in my view it's saturation temperature should also be 100°C at 101.325 kPa.

But in **Cengel Boles Thermodynamics** book it is written that at pressure 101.325 kPa, saturation temperature of water is 99.97°C.

So is it a misprint or saturation temperature and boiling point are different?

Comment: Probably a typo. According to the table Water/steam data table at standard pressure (0.1 MPa) in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_(data_page) the boiling point is ~99.63C. They write stp as 100kPa and also "Note that the boiling point of 100.0 °C is at a pressure of 0.101325 MPa (1 atm), which is the average atmospheric pressure." The same is in http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_properties.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not the same.  The saturation temperature is the temperature at which the vapour pressure $p(T)$ of the liquid equals the partial pressure of the vapour in the ambient atmosphere. When $T$ is below saturation  the vapour  in the atmosphere will condense onto the liquid  surface. When $T$ is above saturation the liquid will evaporate from the liquid  surface until the local atmospheric vapour pressure has increased to that ($p(T)$)  required for equilibrium with the liquid.

The *boiling point* is the temperature at which the vapour pressure of the liquid equals the *total* pressure of the surrounding atmosphere. The total pressure is (approximately) the sum of the vapour pressure in the atmosphere together with that of the other gaseos components ($O_2$ and $N_2$ *etc*.). When the liquid vapour pressure is greater that the total atmospheric pressure,  the liquid can turn into vapour throughout the body of the liquid (i.e.boil) rather than merely evaporate from the surface.

Comment: How could you explain the definition given in Wikipedia? Under the heading **saturation temperature and pressure** it starts with **saturation temperature means boiling point**.                                          https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_point?wprov=sfla1

Comment: @user185991:  Which article are you looking at?  I looked at "Saturation temperature" and got redirected to the article "vapor pressure"  that says just what I wrote above...

Comment: Just follow the link given in my last comment. There you can find a article heading **Saturation temperature and Pressure**  if you want I can provide a screenshot of that :-P

Comment: @user185991:  OK I found your article "Boiling point". The statement "Sat T =boil T" is wrong/misleading.  It only holds when there are only two components" the  liquid and its vapour in a closed system.

Comment: Okk thanks. Plz can u name any source from where I can find your explanation. As I need further depth in this :-D

Comment: As u have said it holds only if there are two components. So sat T = boil T is correct for mixture of saturated liquid and vapour during boiling? Isn't it?? But in Cengel Boles book I found sat T = 99.97°C and boil T = 100°C. What is your opinion upon this?

Comment: @user185991: I think the wiki article on Vapour Pressure  is  OK. On  the "talk page" for your Boiling Point article that the error Boil=Sat and an number of other errors  has been pointed out, but not corrected in the main text. It's always good to look at Wiki talk pages to see if there is a disagreement fight going on. One other place is to look up "dew point" as that *is* the same as the saturation temperature. As for the other disgreemnt, it is small and T$ does have to be a bit over $T_sat$ to boil becuse of surface tension effects.